# What's the most similar license to CC BY-NC or CC BY-NC-SA but for source code?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

The Creative Commons Foundation [recommends against](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software) using the Creative Commons (CC) licenses for software. What's the most similar license to CC BY-NC or CC BY-NC-SA but for source code? To avoid [license proliferation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_proliferation)
, I'd prefer a commonly used license.

Comment: This belongs in the opensource SE